# How do I update my rows in this situation?

Tags: mysql

I have tables A,B

A holds a NETWORK_ID, column and a SUBSCRIPTION_ID

B holds a SUBSCRIPTION_ID(foreign key) and a CARD_ID column

I am going to need to update only CARD_ID (say value 50) to all instances of rows of B that have the NETWORK_ID of say 39.

So if this was one table that would have been easy, just:

```
update table set CARD_ID=50 where NETWORK_ID=39;
```

But how do I go about this here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE tableA A, tableB B
  SET B.CARD_ID = 50
  WHERE A.SUBSCRIPTION_ID = B.SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    AND A.NETWORK_ID = 39
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I get "tablea doesn't exist..." though. It did work when I took the tableA and tableB out, does that seem right?

Comment: `tableA` and `tableB` here are the actual table names, `A` and `B` are aliases used in the query. If `A` and `B` are really your table's name then yes only use that and forget about the aliases since you don't really need them.